# make for loop wait till data is back from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a structure like this:

```
methods: {
  function() {
    //some stuff in here    

    for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
      //Problem in here or around here
      //in here I send something to my API and want to get data back
    }
  }
}
```

*Explenation what I do:* I have an `array` where I want to loop, for every `loop` I send `data` to my API and get `data` back inside the `for-loop`.

*My problem:* I always get the data back in different order because one ot the data is probably bigger and than it takes longer than the others.

*Example:* I send `Array = [1,2,3,4]` and want to get it back in the correct order. But `1` needs more time than `2,3,4` and I get than data back in order `[2,3,4,1]`.

How can I assign my `for-loop` to wait till the first data is back and than go on?

Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Is it working with a for loop exactly like with a forEach?

Comment: Promises or generator functions might help, depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you've read up on `async/await`, you'll still wanna run your requests in parallel to save time, rather than sequentially. `Promise.all` helps here:

```
async function fetchData () {

  const resultsInOrder = await Promise.all(
    // pass an array of Promises
    array.map(element =>
      fetch(/* some arguments based on the element's data */)
        .then(res => res.json())
    )
  )
  // do something with results
}
```

Comment: Map function didn't return a promise.

Comment: @EstusFlask No, `array.map()` is supposed to return an array of Promises. `Promise.all` takes that as a single argument and resolves to an array of resolved values once they're all done, or rejects if any Promise from the array does.

Comment: I mean that there's no return statement and you get an array of undefined

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. I fixed the code.